# Vertical line on Badge progress bar

Tags: support, badge-progress

In the review pages, I see a strange grey vertical line on the Badge progress bar.

[image: Grey vertical line in the middle of the bar]

When inspected, I could see a `border-right` assigned.

```
.meter #badge-progress-bar-vis {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid #9fa6ad;
    width: 25px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Please let me know why this is significant.

Comment: A threshold to cross, to gain one particular badge?

Comment: Badges of certain types can have multiple metallic thresholds: bronze, silver, gold. I think the same progress bar is used for all three.

Comment: Thank you @yivi. Even I'm wondering the same. But why not 3 horizontal bars then? To highlight bronz, silver and gold badges?

Comment: Because only the "next" threshold is highlighted, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @yivi points out in their [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1426539/yivi), it marks a threshold. It marks the requirement for the silver "Reviewer" badge.

Why not for Bronze (Custodian) or Gold (Steward)? Well, bronze only takes 1 review. And the gold badge is when the progress bar is entirely filled.

If there were more than 3 levels, we might see more bars. As it is, you only see the bar for Silver. Because that is the threshold that is not immediately obvious without the vertical marker.

Comment: Thank you. This really helps.